# Where Does "make" Look to Find its Header Files

Tags: make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where Does `"catkin_make", "rosmake" and "make"`  Look to Find its Header Files? (In my question, "make" represents "catkin_make", "rosmake" and "make" :) )
Because of the update of ROS versions, some header files which work in older version do not exist in new version of ROS, which turns out to be a "cannot find xxx header file" error when "make"-ING. What I am going to do is to find out those old header files I need and copy to the path where "make" search for those header files(Is it an advisable behavior?).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189635/where-does-%22make%22-look-to-find-its-header-files/) by [abcgarden](https://answers.ros.org/users/14016/abcgarden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not much magic going on behind the lines. The usual includes that are added by the ROS system are: `/opt/ros/distro/include` and anything that a depend package exports (usually `include` in the package).

For what you are trying to do: Don't! This will NOT fix your problem. Something has changed somewhere. Copying the old headers will most likely not turn back this change. The underlying code the headers referred to is still missing. Even if you also added that you'd probably gain something incompatible.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0